# How was the first Monero coin created?

Tags: history

If I'm correct, you can get Monero coins by:

1. Mining it
2. Buying it from a miner (who mined it at the first place)

Mining is a computation which "legitimizes" transactions on the blockchain. But transaction assumes that one entity/address sends Monero coins to another entity/address. If so, then I have questions:

1. How was first Monero coin created (looks like a chicken-egg problem)?
2. Considering that Monero transactions are private, how can we be sure that someone didn't create a lot of coins at the beginning of blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

> How was first Monero coin created

Every Monero in existence descends from mined Monero, i.e. the coinbase outputs on created blocks.

> Considering that Monero transactions are private, how can we be sure that someone didn't create a lot of coins at the beginning of blockchain?

We can be "sure" because: a) coinbase outputs are *not* private and b) mathematically nodes ensure all newly created outputs (tx outputs) are funded by the tx inputs (which are funded by the tx before, and so on).

Further details: [About supply auditability](https://www.getmonero.org/2020/01/17/auditability.html)

Comment: Can we provide a simplified minimal example, like.. "1. Let's say we start Monero network 2. we created a single mining node 3. next we create a 2 wallets (A and B) 4. wallet A sends coins to wallet B." - so how can wallet A have funds if we need first create a block with transaction? Is it correct?

Comment: Wallet A would have had to have mined a block. Also, a block doesn't have to contain txs.